# SQL Server : calculation on grouped results

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

In SQL Server 2014 from a set of records (say in `TableA`) with date column `[LogDate]` (when it has been logged), status column `[Status]` (say 0 and 1) and UserID [UserID] there might be few records for the same user, with same status at different date.

I want to workout time difference (for all users), between first date it was logged as status = 0 and then first time status was = 1 for each user (so that I can get a sum of that time). I am sure it can be done, I just keep getting into dead-end street. I will appreciate any ideas, so I can move on ...

Example of data:

```
UserId  LogDate     Status
--------------------------
1       01/01/2016  1     
1       02/01/2016  1     
1       07/01/2016  1     
1       10/01/2016  0     
1       11/01/2016  1 
1       12/01/2016  0 
2       01/01/2016  1     
2       02/01/2016  1     
2       07/01/2016  0     
2       10/01/2016  0     
2       11/01/2016  1 
2       12/01/2016  0
```

I would expect to get the result of 9 days for UserID = 1 and 6 days for UserID = 2. Getting sum of those seems to be simple.

Calcs for the number of days for UserID 1: First record with Status=1 is on 10/01/2016, first record for Status=0 is on 01/01/2016. Difference in days between those dates is taken as 9.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: How do you count 9 days? Show please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method to get the first date for each status:

```
select userId,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and status = 0 then logDate end) as logDate_0,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and status = 1 then logDate end) as logDate_1
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userId, status order by logDate) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by userId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (UserId INT, LogDate DATETIME, Status INT)

INSERT INTO @Tbl
select 1 ,      '2016.01.01', 1    union all 
select 1 ,      '2016.01.02', 1    union all 
select 1 ,      '2016.01.07', 1    union all 
select 1 ,      '2016.01.10', 0    union all 
select 1 ,      '2016.01.11', 1    union all
select 1 ,      '2016.01.12', 0    union all
select 2 ,      '2016.01.01', 1    union all 
select 2 ,      '2016.01.02', 1    union all 
select 2 ,      '2016.01.07', 0    union all 
select 2 ,      '2016.01.10', 0    union all 
select 2 ,      '2016.01.11', 1    union all
select 2 ,      '2016.01.12', 0    


SELECT
    M.UserId,
    DATEDIFF(dd, MIN(M.StartLogDate) ,MIN(M.EndLogDate)) AS DayOfLogDate
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        C.UserId,               
        CASE WHEN C.Status = 1 THEN  C.LogDate ELSE (SELECT NULL) END AS StartLogDate,          
        CASE WHEN C.Status = 0 THEN  C.LogDate ELSE (SELECT NULL) END AS EndLogDate         
    FROM 
        @Tbl C
) M
GROUP BY
    M.UserId
```

Output:

```
UserId  DayOfLogDate
1       9
2       6
```